# Jquery is not completing the append of elements - last two are not appeneded

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I receive an array from ajax call and build a series of radio boxes using the array's elements. Only some of the radio boxes are appended, not all, eg. out of 4 elements in the array only first two are appended, out of 3 elements only the first is appended. 
The array from ajax call is as expected. The **for** loop works correctly, ie. the text to be inserted is built as expected, yet the **append** is not appending the expected lot but only some. I've run out of ideas...
here's my **html**:

```
<table class="std-table">
   <tr>
      <td><div id="areas"></div></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

and **javascript**:

```
    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#property-details-page', function(){   

    all_areas = new Array();
    var Q001Data = "sql=Q001&dbcall=sql_get_results_array&memid="+<?php echo $member_id?>+"&propid="+<?php echo $property_id?>;
    $.ajax({ // ### AJAX to get ALL AREAS on page load ###
        url:"pl_process_ajax_call_property_features.php",
        type:"POST",
        data : Q001Data,
        success:function(msg){
            $("#areas").html('<fieldset id="all-areas-radio" data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true"></fieldset>');
            all_areas = JSON.parse(msg);
            var textToInsert = '';
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < all_areas.length; ++i) {
                var area = JSON.stringify(all_areas[i][0]);
                alert(area+i);
                textToInsert  += '<input type="radio" class="all-areas" name="property-area" id="' + area + '" value="' + area + '"><label for="' + area + '">' + area + '</label>';    
                alert(textToInsert);
            }
            $("#all-areas-radio").append(textToInsert);    
            $("[type=radio]").checkboxradio();
            $("[data-role=controlgroup]").controlgroup().controlgroup("refresh");
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Error Q001!");
        },
    }); // ### AJAX to get ALL AREAS on page load ###
    }); // ### document.on
```

The alerts in the loop are just to see what's happening inside. The **textToInsert** is built correctly, but then **append** is missing out on last two elements.
I've tried to **append** inside the loop but that made no difference to the outcome. Please help.

Comment: What does you browser's developer tools tell you? Are you getting an errors shown in the dev tool's console? Have you tried using the debugger in the dev tools?

Comment: No errors in console, Chrome or FF. I use Eclipse for development and don't think the debugger works. I do mainly php and this is my first page that I have to do entirely in js... not quite an expert ;-(

Comment: Not your IDE, but the dev tools of your browser. In IE, FF, and Chrome: press F12 (other browsers include dev tools but could use a different shortcut).

Comment: Ah, yes, I'm using these but don't know how to use debugger... just watch the console...

Answer (score 3):

You are incrementing your counter too soon. Instead of ++i, try i++

Comment: Someone else has suggested that and I've tried, it made no difference,  both `++i` and `i++` seem to be incrementing the counter at the end of the loop, ie after all statements have been executed. I've checked this via an alert display.

Comment: ++i means increment i before using it. Which means that on your first iteration you are grabbing your second array index, .. and also means that you are going to finish your loop early because you have already counted ahead. Have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/z1haze/x6umaun4/

Comment: Agree entirely with the concept. However whether `++i` or `i++` my loop loops through my complete array of 4 elements showing value of `i` as expected, ie 0,1,2 and 3 and all correct array elements in the right order. but it only appends two... I've also tested that in your fiddle example, no difference.

Comment: you dont have to.. just get the response from your working server, store it in a fiddle variable and run the loop

Comment: OK, I did. I've got all my 4 radio boxes. That would point it towards ajax output and JSON? I've done this before with checkboxes and it worked sweet...

Comment: link to the fiddle you tested it on?

Comment: Sorry, I'm in OZ, had to have some sleep ;-). The fiddle link: [https://jsfiddle.net/wlukasz/9hno6pyh . The last two lines in js are for jqm markup. What I have now discovered is that commenting out these two lines allows for all 4 items to be shown but no jqm markup. With the lines on the buttons come out nice but last two are missing. That's on my computer. In fiddle they always come up ok but no jqm markup.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = 0; i <= all_areas.length; i++) {
    var area = JSON.stringify(all_areas[i][0]);
    alert(area + i);
    textToInsert  += '<input type="radio" class="all-areas" name="property-area" id="' + area + '" value="' + area + '"><label for="' + area + '">' + area + '</label>';    
    alert(textToInsert);
}
```

If using for loop like this:

You are using `i < all_areas.length` because variable `i` strats from 0 so you can use `i <= all_areas.length;` 
and also `++i` you write pre increment; you can use post increment `i++` then you can get all the radio buttons..

Comment: I could agree with `i++` but I think `i < all_areas.length` is correct. Take an array with 4 elements, I want `i<4`, ie 0,1,2,3, which is 4 elements... by the way `i++` did not make a difference...